# what is the reason to raise the error without using firebase in android

Tags: android, google-signin

Error:

```
Process: com.xportsoft.epicsudoku, PID: 5380                                                           
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
```

Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
defaultConfig {
    .....
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'`

dependency completely in your project. Use only specific library dependencies from `google-play-services` library that are required to your project. For example if you want use google places then use following line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```

Firebase is now part of the Google, so this problem was occurring in your project.

For more refer this [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)